# dotnet iqsharp install gives error "FileNotFoundError: The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: programming, q#

[image]

installing  Q# version g --version 0.1.2.3 in jupyter. but this command line dotnet iqsharp install   responds  system cannot find path specified .  what should i do . 
i have also installed vscode 2019 is it the cause. 
i need help please

Comment: Which version of `Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp` do you have installed? You can check by running `dotnet iqsharp --version`. The latest version should be 0.11.2006.403. If you don't have that, can you try to run `dotnet tool update -g Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp`, close and re-open your command prompt, and run `dotnet iqsharp install` again?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed IQ# with `--version 0.1.2.3`, then this would have installed a very old version on your machine, which had [this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp/issues/63) that is probably affecting you here. You can run `dotnet iqsharp --version` to see which version you have installed. ([Check here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/relnotes/) for the latest released version numbers.)

If so, you should install the latest version of IQ# by running `dotnet tool update -g Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp`, followed by `dotnet iqsharp install`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: its working now   Gracias  am grateful